# Actionscript: How to handle events with same type but with different function listener?

Tags: ios, events, actionscript, upload

I'm attempting to make a sample application for ios using Actionscript (adobe air). But I'm having problems concerning events/event handling. My app basically gives the user the option to take a picture or select one from the camera roll to upload to a server. If the user decides to take a photo, I have to save that photo to the device's camera roll. The part of the code I'm having problem with is below:

```
private function readMediaData():void {
    //set up some variables and data

    var file:File = tempDir.resolvePath(filename);
    var stream:FileStream = new FileStream(); 
    stream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE); 
    stream.writeBytes(imageBytes); 
    stream.close();

    file.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, uploadComplete, false, 0, true);

    //upload file here
}

private function uploadComplete(event:Event):void {
    //selectedImage is the MediaPromise
    if (selectedImage.file == null) {
         loader = new Loader();
         loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderCompleted);
         loader.loadFilePromise(selectedImage);
    }
}

private function loaderCompleted(event:Event):void {
    //save image
}
```

The upload is working fine, but once the upload is completed, I get a somewhat infinite loop  between loaderCompleted and uploadComplete resulting in multiple images being uploaded to the server. I tried removing the listener for the file once it has entered the uploadComplete function but still get the same result. My guess is that once the event listener for the loader is registered, it triggers an Event.COMPLETE notification which both method (or object) still recognizes. Is there a way to properly handle events with the same type but coming from different objects and with different function listeners?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the listener to the stream instead of to the file:

```
// Changed the 'file' with 'stream'
stream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, uploadComplete, false, 0, true);
```